# How to download csv.gz file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, request

How to download csv.gz file in Node.js and convert it to JSON? I tried this:

```
request.get("https://onesignal.s3.amazonaws.com/csv_exports/appID_etc.csv.gz", (error, res, body) => {
     console.log(body)   
})
```

but it prints  me this output which I can't work with like converting it to JSON:

[image]

Comment: The [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is deprecated; don't use it.

Comment: what should i use instead @Quentin

Comment: The documentation for the request module (linked above) makes several recommendations.